# Use standard salesforce component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience

Can we use standard salesforce lightning component?

I have a requirement where based on some condition I need to invoke lead convert pop up in lightning experience
I know I can create lightning component and then invoke it using lightning action.
But I want to know if there are any standard lightning components available from salesforce.
If yes then how can we invoke them and what all things we can use.

On clicking convert button from lead I can see there are lot of Events fired by salesforce.
Please see the screenshots:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: The standard lighting components can be found in the available components through the app builder

Answer (score 1):

> A Short Answer : "NO", if you want to avoid your logic breaking in production when you least expect it to.

As far as i am aware, ui:createPanel is not a documented one. And as such there is no guarantee that it would continue to work in the future releases.

The issue with undocumented events is that, the behavior can change at any point of time due to patch / release ( Not essentially the major ones, it can change with nightly patch as well ).

So, a general rule of thumb : Do not use  something that is not a part of documentation.Please find the reference for listed events

Reference : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_events.htm

That being said, even if you fire ui:createPanel, you would need parameter as you have inspected below, if you take a look closely, you have salesforce authored namespaces such as "runtime_sale_lead" etc. You would get into quite some issue if you try manipulating these elements.

So the best approach would be to use documented way of using a component with interfaces **"force:lightningQuickAction or force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader"** .

1. Create a quick action lightning component.
2. Use v.recordId to get the current sobject id, get the required params such as Opportunity name, Account Name etc.
3. Use an apex server side controller to convert the lead ( LeadConvert apex class).
4. Based on response show success toast or error toast, redirect to the converted sobject.

Reference : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dml_convertLead.htm

Comment: Is there any recent update to access standard lead convert action in custom lightning component?